# It doesn't work to double tapping the content page of iframe on ipod safari

Tags: iframe, safari, ipod

I am confused in iframe behavior on ipod safari. I write a sample html page "index.html" and add touchstart/touchmove/touchend event. I try it on ipod safari.

Use double tapping to scale up the content page and show different document.body.clientWidth and document.body.clientHeight.

I write another page "iframe.html" including iframe. I try it and scale up but show the same document.body.clientWidth/document.body.clientHeight? I have no idea for this problem. If you have any idea, please share your idea with me. Thanks.

The content of "iframe.html":

```
<iframe src="index.html" id="mainFrame"> </iframe>
```

The content of "index.html":

```
var targetToucheSize = 0; 
function handleStart(evt) { ... } 
function handleMove(evt) { ... }
function handleEnd(evt) { 
    var winW; 
    var winH; 
    if (targetToucheSize == 2) {
        if (!document.all) { 
            winW = window.innerWidth; 
            winH = window.innerHeight;
        } else { 
            winW = document.body.clientWidth; 
            winH = document.body.clientHeight; 
        } 
        alert(" winW " + winW + " winH " + winH); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I copied code snippets to question body to make them more clear. Please do it yourself next time, thanks.